# Cannot read JSON nested object in Android

Tags: php, android, laravel

I'm creating an Android app and trying to read json data returned from PHP(Laravel).

Here is the PHP code:

```
    $id = $request->input('id');

    $customer = Customer::find(array('id' => $id));

    if(!isset($customer))
        return json_encode(array('message'=>'empty'));
    else
        return json_encode(array('message'=>'found', 'customer' => $customer));
```

Here is the JSON response I get:

```
{"message":"found","customer":[{"id":1,"phone":"1234567890","name":"abc","photo":"","status":"active","created_at":"2016-01-18 09:23:10","updated_at":"-0001-11-30 00:00:00"}]}
```

Here is the Android code:

```
    client.get(Utility.server + "/get-customer-info", params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
        // When the response returned by REST has Http response code '200'
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String response) {
            try {
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);

                if (obj.getString("message").equals("found")) {

                    JSONObject customer = obj.getJSONObject("customer");

                    String id = customer.getString("id");
                    String name = customer.getString("name");
                    String phone = customer.getString("photo");
                    String photo = customer.getString("photo");
                    String status = customer.getString("status");
                    String createdAt = customer.getString("created_at");

                    Utility.customer = new Customer(id, name, phone, photo, status, createdAt);

                    Intent i = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                else if (obj.getString("message").equals("empty")) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, WelcomeActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid data", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error Occured [Server's JSON response might be invalid]!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

The inner customer object is like an Array and I'm not able to read it using JSONObject or JSONArray. I get type mismatch error for the statement:

```
JSONObject customer = obj.getJSONObject("customer");
```

Comment: is "customer" is an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from your JSON response it's clearly visible that it is `JsonArray` not `JsonObject`. Get your 1st object of customer like this :

```
JSONArray customerArr = obj.getJSONArray("customer");
JsonObject customer=customerArr.getJSONObject(0);
```

If you are having more than one data in customer array, take use of for loop

```
for(int i=0;i<customerArr.length;i++)
{
     JsonObject customer=customerArr.getJSONObject(i);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

change your code to below way

```
 JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
  if (obj.getString("message").equals("found")) {
     JSONArray customer = obj.getJSONArray("customer");
     if (customer != null && customer.length() > 0) {
     for (int kk = 0; kk <customer.length(); kk++) {
          JSONObject json1 = customer.optJSONObject(kk);
          String id = json1.getString("id");
          String name = json1.getString("name");
          String phone = json1.getString("photo");
          String photo = json1.getString("photo");
          String status = json1.getString("status");
          String createdAt = json1.getString("created_at");
          Utility.customer = new Customer(id, name, phone, photo, status, createdAt);
        }
        // your other code
    }
 }
```